# Conversion calculator using polymorphism and Swing

Tags: java, beginner, converting, swing, polymorphism

This is my first attempt at a program (outside of school) and I was trying to implement and learn polymorphism on a conversion calculator for volumes and weights.

I found myself using long `switch` statements in the GUI to test user inputs against the units in order to make the calculations. Is there a better alternative to using `switch` statements here that might shorten the code, make it more readable and possibly improve efficiency?

Did I make good use of polymorphism?

I am open to any constructive criticism but again, I'm learning so please offer an explanation with your criticism/suggestions.

```
public class ConversionLayout {
    NumberFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#####");
    private JRadioButton volume = new JRadioButton("volume");
    private JRadioButton weight = new JRadioButton("weight");
    private JComboBox<String> selection1 = new JComboBox<String>();
    private JComboBox<String> selection2 = new JComboBox<String>();
    private DefaultComboBoxModel<String> unitSet1 = new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>();
    private DefaultComboBoxModel<String> unitSet2 = new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>();
    private JTextField userInput1;
    private JTextField userInput2;
    private JLabel topLabel;
    private JLabel equals;
    private JPanel topPanel;
    private JPanel calcInput;
    private JPanel radioPanel;
    private String[] units = { "ml", "litre", "oz", "cup", "pint", "tbsp",
        "tsp", "gallon", "quart" };
    private String[] units1 = { "g", "kg", "oz", "lb" };
    private String unit1;
    private String unit2;
    private String result;
    private double amountValue;
    private Conversion ml = new ConvertFromMillilitre();
    private Conversion cup = new ConvertFromCup();
    private Conversion gallon = new ConvertFromGallon();
    private Conversion litre = new ConvertFromLitre();
    private Conversion oz = new ConvertFromOz();
    private Conversion pint = new ConvertFromPint();
    private Conversion quart = new ConvertFromQuart();
    private Conversion tbsp = new ConvertFromTbsp();
    private Conversion tsp = new ConvertFromTsp();
    private Conversion g = new ConvertFromGram();
    private Conversion kg = new ConvertFromKilogram();
    private Conversion ozWeight = new ConvertFromOzWeight();
    private Conversion lb = new ConvertFromPound();

public ConversionLayout() {
    equals = new JLabel("=");
    equals.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    userInput1 = new JTextField();
    userInput2 = new JTextField();

    for (int i = 0; i < units.length; i++) {
        unitSet1.addElement(units[i]);
        unitSet2.addElement(units[i]);
    }

    selection1.setModel(unitSet1);
    selection2.setModel(unitSet2);
    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
    group.add(volume);
    group.add(weight);
    volume.setSelected(true);
    radioPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2));
    radioPanel.add(volume);
    radioPanel.add(weight);

    volume.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            unitSet1.removeAllElements();
            unitSet2.removeAllElements();
            for (int i = 0; i < units.length; i++) {
                unitSet1.addElement(units[i]);
                unitSet2.addElement(units[i]);
            }
        }

    });

    weight.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            unitSet1.removeAllElements();
            unitSet2.removeAllElements();
            for (int i = 0; i < units1.length; i++) {
                unitSet1.addElement(units1[i]);
                unitSet2.addElement(units1[i]);
            }
        }

    });

    setDefaultValues("ml", "ml");

    calcInput = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 5));

    calcInput.add(selection1);
    calcInput.add(userInput1);
    calcInput.add(equals);
    calcInput.add(selection2);
    calcInput.add(userInput2);

    topLabel = new JLabel("Please enter your selections below:");
    topPanel = new JPanel();
    topPanel.add(topLabel);

    unitSelections();

    UserEntries entry = new UserEntries();
    userInput1.addActionListener(entry);
    userInput2.addActionListener(entry);

}// end layout constructor

private void setDefaultValues(String val1, String val2) {
    if (unit1 == null) {
        this.unit1 = val1;
        this.unit2 = val2;
    }
}

// ItemListener to set the value of the unit1 and unit2 fields based on user
// selections
private void unitSelections() {
    selection1.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                String selection = selection1.getSelectedItem().toString();
                unit1 = selection;
            }
        }
    });

    selection2.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                String selection = selection2.getSelectedItem().toString();
                unit2 = selection;
            }
        }
    });
}

// sets the values for userInput to each conversion unit
private void setValues(double userInput) {
    ml.setValue(userInput);
    ml.getValue();

    cup.setValue(userInput);
    cup.getValue();

    gallon.setValue(userInput);
    gallon.getValue();

    litre.setValue(userInput);
    litre.getValue();

    oz.setValue(userInput);
    oz.getValue();

    pint.setValue(userInput);
    pint.getValue();

    quart.setValue(userInput);
    quart.getValue();

    tbsp.setValue(userInput);
    tbsp.getValue();

    tsp.setValue(userInput);
    tsp.getValue();

    tsp.setValue(userInput);
    tsp.getValue();

    g.setValue(userInput);
    g.getValue();

    kg.setValue(userInput);
    kg.getValue();

    ozWeight.setValue(userInput);
    ozWeight.getValue();

    lb.setValue(userInput);
    lb.getValue();
}


// class for setting user input values on either JTextField
private class UserEntries implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //if the volume JRadioButton is selected we will run the switch on volume units.
        if (volume.isSelected()) {
            // if userInput1 triggers ActionEvent we check for unit1 value and
            // convert to unit2 value
            if (e.getSource() == userInput1) {
                String value = userInput1.getText();
                // ensure entry is a numerical value
                try {
                    amountValue = Double.parseDouble(value);
                    if (amountValue < 0) {
                        throw new NumberFormatException();
                    }
                } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(userInput1,
                            "Please enter a numeric value to convert.");
                }
                // sets the userInput value to the unit1
                setValues(amountValue);
                switch (unit1) {
                case "ml":
                    result = String.valueOf(ml.convertTo(unit2));
                    userInput2
                            .setText(df.format(Double.parseDouble(result)));
                    break;
                case "cup":
                    result = String.valueOf(cup.convertTo(unit2));
                    userInput2
                            .setText(df.format(Double.parseDouble(result)));
                    break;
                case "gallon":
                    result = String.valueOf(gallon.convertTo(unit2));
                    userInput2
                            .setText(df.format(Double.parseDouble(result)));
                    break;
                case "litre":
                    result = String.valueOf(litre.convertTo(unit2));
                    userInput2
                            .setText(df.format(Double.parseDouble(result)));
                    break;
                case "oz":
                    result = String.valueOf(oz.convertTo(unit2));
                    userInput2
                            .setText(df.format(Double.parseDouble(result)));
                    break;
                case "pint":
                    result = String.valueOf(pint.convertTo(unit2));
                    userInput2
                            .setText(df.format(Double.parseDouble(result)));
                    break;
                case "quart":
                    result = String.valueOf(quart.convertTo(unit2));
                    userInput2
                            .setText(df.format(Double.parseDouble(result)));
                    break;
                case "tbsp":
                    result = String.valueOf(tbsp.convertTo(unit2));
                    userInput2
                            .setText(df.format(Double.parseDouble(result)));
                    break;
                case "tsp":
                    result = String.valueOf(tsp.convertTo(unit2));
                    userInput2
                            .setText(df.format(Double.parseDouble(result)));
                    break;

                }//end switch

                // if userInput2 triggers ActionEvent we check for unit2
                // value
                // and convert to unit1 value
            } else if (e.getSource() == userInput2) {
                String value = userInput2.getText();
                try {
                    amountValue = Double.parseDouble(value);
                    if (amountValue < 0) {
                        throw new NumberFormatException();
                    }
                } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                    JOptionPane
                            .showMessageDialog(userInput2,
                                    "Please enter a positive numeric value to convert.");
                }
                // sets the userInput value to the units
                setValues(amountValue);
                switch (unit2) {
                case "ml":
                    result = String.valueOf(ml.convertTo(unit1));
                    userInput1
                            .setText(df.format(Double.parseDouble(result)));
                    break;
                case "cup":
                    result = String.valueOf(cup.convertTo(unit1));
                    userInput1
                            .setText(df.format(Double.parseDouble(result)));
                    break;
                case "gallon":
                    result = String.valueOf(gallon.convertTo(unit1));
                    userInput1
                            .setText(df.format(Double.parseDouble(result)));
                    break;
                case "litre":
                    result = String.valueOf(litre.convertTo(unit1));
                    userInput1
                            .setText(df.format(Double.parseDouble(result)));
                    break;
                case "oz":
                    result = String.valueOf(oz.convertTo(unit1));
                    userInput1
                            .setText(df.format(Double.parseDouble(result)));
                    break;
                case "pint":
                    result = String.valueOf(pint.convertTo(unit1));
                    userInput1
                            .setText(df.format(Double.parseDouble(result)));
                    break;
                case "quart":
                    result = String.valueOf(quart.convertTo(unit1));
                    userInput1
                            .setText(df.format(Double.parseDouble(result)));
                    break;
                case "tbsp":
                    result = String.valueOf(tbsp.convertTo(unit1));
                    userInput1
                            .setText(df.format(Double.parseDouble(result)));
                    break;
                case "tsp":
                    result = String.valueOf(tsp.convertTo(unit1));
                    userInput1
                            .setText(df.format(Double.parseDouble(result)));
                    break;
                }//end switch
            }//end inner if/else
        //if the weight JRadioButton is selected we will run the switch on weight units.    
        } else if (weight.isSelected()) {
            // if userInput1 triggers ActionEvent we check for unit1
            // value and convert to unit2 value
            if (e.getSource() == userInput1) {
                String value = userInput1.getText();
                // ensure entry is a numerical value
                try {
                    amountValue = Double.parseDouble(value);
                    if (amountValue < 0) {
                        throw new NumberFormatException();
                    }
                } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(userInput1,
                            "Please enter a numeric value to convert.");
                }
                // sets the userInput value to the unit1
                setValues(amountValue);
                switch (unit1) {
                case "g":
                    result = String.valueOf(g.convertTo(unit2));
                    userInput2
                            .setText(df.format(Double.parseDouble(result)));
                    break;
                case "kg":
                    result = String.valueOf(kg.convertTo(unit2));
                    userInput2
                            .setText(df.format(Double.parseDouble(result)));
                    break;
                case "oz":
                    result = String.valueOf(ozWeight.convertTo(unit2));
                    userInput2
                            .setText(df.format(Double.parseDouble(result)));
                    break;
                case "lb":
                    result = String.valueOf(lb.convertTo(unit2));
                    userInput2
                            .setText(df.format(Double.parseDouble(result)));
                    break;
                }//end switch
                // if userInput2 triggers ActionEvent we check for unit2
                // value and convert to unit1 value
            } else if (e.getSource() == userInput2) {
                String value = userInput2.getText();
                try {
                    amountValue = Double.parseDouble(value);
                    if (amountValue < 0) {
                        throw new NumberFormatException();
                    }
                } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                    JOptionPane
                            .showMessageDialog(userInput2,
                                    "Please enter a positive numeric value to convert.");
                }
                // sets the userInput value to the units
                setValues(amountValue);
                switch (unit2) {
                case "g":
                    result = String.valueOf(g.convertTo(unit1));
                    userInput1
                            .setText(df.format(Double.parseDouble(result)));
                    break;
                case "kg":
                    result = String.valueOf(kg.convertTo(unit1));
                    userInput1
                            .setText(df.format(Double.parseDouble(result)));
                    break;
                case "oz":
                    result = String.valueOf(ozWeight.convertTo(unit1));
                    userInput1
                            .setText(df.format(Double.parseDouble(result)));
                    break;
                case "lb":
                    result = String.valueOf(lb.convertTo(unit1));
                    userInput1
                            .setText(df.format(Double.parseDouble(result)));
                    break;
                }//end switch
            }//end inner if/else
        }//end outer if/else for JRadioButton selections
    }//end ActionPerformed
}// end UserEntries

private void buildGui() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Conversion Calculator");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 1, 0, 5));
    frame.getContentPane().add(topPanel);
    frame.getContentPane().add(radioPanel);
    frame.getContentPane().add(calcInput);
    frame.setSize(400, 150);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            ConversionLayout run = new ConversionLayout();
            run.buildGui();
        }
    });
}//end main

}// end ConversionLayout
```

[GitHub](https://github.com/bmcma/Conversion-Calculator/tree/53c5be781ba8027d03ee54f9b845a067f0f94f97)

Answer (score 1):

I would use some kind of Factory for this. If want to write it short for the sake of simplicity it would look something like this:

```
public class ConversionFactory {

private Map<String, Conversion> conversionMapping = new HashMap<String, Conversion>();

private static final Map<String, ConversionFactory> factories=new HashMap<>();

{
    ConversionFactory volumeFactory=new ConversionFactory();
    volumeFactory.registerNewConversion("ml", new ConvertFromMillilitre());
    volumeFactory.registerNewConversion("litre", new ConvertFromLitre());
    volumeFactory.registerNewConversion("oz", new ConvertFromOz());
    volumeFactory.registerNewConversion("cup", new ConvertFromCup());
    volumeFactory.registerNewConversion("pint", new ConvertFromPint());
    volumeFactory.registerNewConversion("tbsp", new ConvertFromTbsp());
    volumeFactory.registerNewConversion("tsp", new ConvertFromTsp());
    volumeFactory.registerNewConversion("gallon", new ConvertFromGallon());
    volumeFactory.registerNewConversion("quart", new ConvertFromQuart());
    factories.put("volume", volumeFactory);
    ConversionFactory weightFactory=new ConversionFactory();
    weightFactory.registerNewConversion("g", new ConvertFromGram());
    weightFactory.registerNewConversion("kg", new ConvertFromKilogram());
    weightFactory.registerNewConversion("oz", new ConvertFromOzWeight());
    weightFactory.registerNewConversion("lb", new ConvertFromPound());
    factories.put("weight", weightFactory);

}

private void registerConversion(String key, Conversion conv) {
    conversionMapping.put(key, conv);
}

public void registerNewConversion(String key, Conversion conv) {
    registerConversion(key, conv);
}

public Conversion findConversion(String key) {
    return conversionMapping.get(key);
}

public Set<String> getAvailableConversions() {
    return conversionMapping.keySet();
}

public static ConversionFactory getConversionFactory(String type) {
    return factories.get(type);
}
}
```

Of course it would be probably better to separate `volume` and `weight` factory initialization to separate classes. It is also possily better to use `Enums` instead of plain `Strings` for `Factory` and `Conversion` keys.
Then your switch statements could be replaced with this:

```
...
private void convert(String unitType, String amountValue, String unit1, String unit2) {
        Conversion volConversion = ConversionFactory.getConversionFactory(unitType).findConversion(unit1);
        volConversion.setValue(amountValue);
        volConversion.getValue();
        String result = String.valueOf(volConversion.convertTo(unit2));
        userInput2.setText(df.format(Double.parseDouble(result)));
}
...
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     ...
     convert("volume", amountValue, unit1, unit2);
     ...
     convert("weight", amountValue, unit2, unit1);
     ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm reading up on both `Factory` and `Enums` and I will try and implement them. You say the `Enums` are possibly better? Why are they better or is it just a preference thing?

Comment: It depends on concrete use case. You can compare `Enums` with `Constants`. Enums sometimes offer better structure, you can list them, group them, it's often easier to select concrete `Enum`.